# How to open Clipboard History in RDP session in Windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, clipboard, rdp

I can't open **Windows Clipboard History** with **Windows + V** in Windows 10. I'm using **Microsoft Remote Desktop** on my **macbook air** to connect to remote machine via **RDP** and not able to open it. It's just paste last copied record and not showing the whole history. That's window I'm trying to open:
[clipboard history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjaoQ.png)

Comment: yes, it gets me last record only, not the whole list as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Clipboard History in Windows over RDP from a MacBook Air. I solved it by taking the following steps in Windows:

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
2. Navigate to the location below in the left pane of Local Group Policy Editor to:

   Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\OS Policies​
3. In the right pane of OS Policies in Local Group Policy Editor, double click/tap on the Allow Clipboard History policy to edit (Enable) it.
4. Reboot computer.
5. Enable Clipboard History from the normal Windows settings.